# Assistance with updating a group of Linux machines from a Powershell script or some other script

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, ssh, scripting

I know I can use putty to ssh into each Linux machine and update CentOS servers...but I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction on how I can do this perhaps from PowerShell or some other scripting language from within Windows.

We use batchpatch for patching our Windows machines...works like a charm.  But we've been adding some Linux machines to the mix and I'd like to continue to use batchpatch for this task.  Batchpatch does not have the ability to talk to Linux (no ssh support)...but batchpatch does allow me to execute scripts so I'm going to test out running a script against each machine listed in my batchpatch view.

What I'm looking to do is through a Windows script connect to a Linux machine and issue the commands to patch "yum upgrade".  We have a common user added to each of our Linux machines so I can execute the script using this account (and this account has nopasswd sudoer access as well so I should I be able to execute sudo instructions in the script without having to type in my password during the running of the script).  Does anyone have an example of a script or can point me to a script that would get me started in my testing of this task?

Thank you in advance for any advice you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute one line script, probably the easiest solution is plink.exe.  Read here about it, it included to putty packet: https://cmatskas.com/run-ssh-with-powershell/

If you want more control in SSH session, you can use POS-SSH powershell module. https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH